# Suppressing a divide by zero error on initial form entry waiting for input

Tags: php, math

I have a small form that does a very basic function - user inputs any number, and then selects from a dropdown from 1 to 12 to divide that number.  The drop down default is preset to select "1"

When the form displays / initializes, a divide by 0 error is displayed, but upon clicking the calculate button - even without selecting anything or entering a number in the first box, the error disappears and the form correctly calculates a "zero" value.

By my math = the initial box variable not having anything in it should be "zero", and the select dropdown is default to "1".  Zero / 1 = 0 and there should be no divide by error, but in it's initial state without any value defined I get one.

I have tried setting an initial value for the first variable of "zero" and I get the same results.

```
<?php
       $value1 = $_POST['value1'];
       $value2 = $_POST['value2'];
?>
              <form action="tax_calculator.php" method="post">
    Enter the total amount of your tax bill <br>
                    <input type="text" name="value1"/><br><br>

    How many payments would you like to make? <br>
                    <select select name="value2" id="value2">
                    <option selected="selected">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    </select><br><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Calculate My Payment"/>
              </form>

    Your payment amount would be: <B>$<?php echo round($value1 / $value2 ,2); ?></b>
```

Comment: simple set value="0" <input type="text" name="value1" value="0' />

Comment: I did try this exact code initially thinking that maybe one of the variables wasn't assuming "0" with no input given at the load of the page, but I still receive the error.  Thank you kindly though.

Comment: try my below answer @Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **isset** to check values set or not  and check the value is not using  **!empty**

```
  $round =0;

 if(isset($_POST['value1'],$_POST['value2']) && !empty($_POST['value1']) && !empty($_POST['value2']))
{

   $round =  round($_POST['value1']/ $_POST['value2'] ,2);

}

Your payment amount would be: <B>$<?php echo $round; ?></b>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly - I just had to add <?php and ?> around the scripting part as I jump in and out of PHP and HTML to keep it all in one block.  THANK YOU!

Comment: glad to help you @KevinEstey